# dynamic CSS in JSF

Tags: java, css, jsf, dynamic, jsf-2

I read [this](http://commoninterview.com/Programming_Interview_Questions/what-is-dynamic-css-1/) article about dynamic CSS.

I would like to **generate** CSS based on db parameters.

Something similar to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="mydynamicCss.ashx?cssCode=mainPage" type="text/css"/>`

What is the best way to implement it in JSF?

I am using JSF2.0

Comment: An alternative way would be using EL in your css files, assuming you treat them as a resource (`<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="yourcss.css"/>`). You can get the `ExternalContext`, for example, and try to do something with it. Although I can't figure out right now a way to get a paramter from the css file.

Comment: What is the advantage of using this ability? I don't have the CSS pre-defined I want to create it on the fly

Comment: oh, well. Then a Servlet is indeed the best option. If you want one per session, no problem. Just do this check in the Servlet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather use an extra servlet for this purpose, possibly something using velocity/freemarker or maybe there are existing libraries supporting css generation. The href link would be mapped to this servlet instead of JSF servlet. I haven't really seen a css taglib for JSF.

Comment: However, I don't want this to occur each time that the page is loaded. only once per session

Comment: If you encoded your parameters in the URL, you could setup caching or answer with HTTP 304 Not modified. On the other hand these 2 template libraries are much faster than JSF so it would barely impact performance - assuming you do full page refreshes with header included.

Comment: I didn't understand your answer about HTTP 403

Comment: You can find some info here http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/servlet/ch03_06.htm.

Answer (score -1):

I don't truly understand what you mean, but we create "dynamic" CSS by using conditions.

For instance

```
<a:repeat var="foo" value="#{foos}">
  <li class="#{foo % 2 == 0?'odd':'even'}">
   ....
</a:repeat>
```

Comment: No. I don't want to use it for each component. I want to generate the CSS dynamically